# External tensor product of quasi coherent sheaf

Tags: tensor-products

When is the following map possible?

$A\boxtimes A(\mathcal{G}\times\mathcal{G})\rightarrow A(\mathcal{G}) \otimes A(\mathcal{G})$;
where $\mathcal{G}$ is a group scheme, $A$ is a quasi coherent sheaf(of algebras) over $\mathcal{G}$ and $\boxtimes$  is the external tensor product of a sheaf given by $\pi_1^*A\otimes\pi_2^* A $.

In general, for any open set $U$, $A\boxtimes A(U\times U)\rightarrow A(U)\otimes A(U)$ doesnt hold true. What are the conditions required for this to hold? Will generation of $A$ by global sections suffice?

Please help.

Comment: There is a map in the other direction. Do you want to get a inverse of this?

Comment: Yes, I need a non-zero map. (isomorphism even better!)

I know there is always a map in other direction. But when would the inverse(non-zero) map exist? I need to know the conditions that one require for this inverse to exist. Will generation of $\mathcal{A}$ by global sections be sufficient condition for this map to exist?

Comment: Let $(\mathcal{G},\mathcal{O})$ be an affine scheme, and $\mathcal{A}$  a quasi coherent sheaf over $\mathcal{G}$.
Is $(\mathcal{A}\boxtimes \mathcal{A})(\mathcal{G}\mathcal{G})=\mathcal{A}(\mathcal{G})\otimes \mathcal{A}(\mathcal{G})$ ?

Comment: I meant $\mathcal{G}\times \mathcal{G}$ in the above statement.